# EnablePageMethods in asp.net doesn't work in plesk panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

i have problem with execute page methods when i upload my website on Plesk panel .

my code in page.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

and i call java script like

```
    function checkUserMeliCode(meliCode)
    {
        PageMethods.IsMeliAvailable(meliCode, onSucceeded);
    }
    function onSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
        if (methodName == "IsMeliAvailable") {
            if (result == true) {
                spanAv.innerHTML = "<span style='color:green'> <li class='fa fa-check' ></li> معتبر </span>";
            }
            else {
                spanAv.innerHTML = "<span style='color:Red'> <li class='fa fa-warning' ></li> قبلا ثبت گردیده است </span>";
            }

        }
```

and i have this code in code behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool IsMeliAvailable(string Meli)
{
    Admin_Req tbl_Admin = new Admin_Req();
    tbl_Admin.Req_MeliCode = Meli;
    DataTable result_req = tbl_Admin.Get_ReqByMeliCode();

    if (result_req.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }


}
```

every thing work good until i upload my web site to panel Plesk version 9.5 
any solution ? 
i think i have to add something to web.conf to allow plesk send and receive PageMethod

it's link of uploaded code

[website Link](http://sandogh.wweebb.ir)

Webmethod call for 4th input it's kind of number, and i call pagemethod when number count equal 10 . so fill it until it's count equal 10 and look at console

Comment: What exactly is the error? The page is not rendering the js code of the page or when it is called you get an error on the request?

Comment: http://sandogh.wweebb.ir/

Comment: it's link of uploaded file , you can look at console

Answer (score 0):

the page method need to set path ... if you don't set path for page method it will get current page ...

in conclusion when you upload your website to your host . you have to set page method path .

```
 PageMethods.set_path("pages/AdminReq.aspx");
```